# PHP undefined variable error when defined

Tags: php

For some reason, when $taxRate and $tax are called on line 36 and 39, I am getting the error "Warning: Undefined variable $taxRate in A:\MAMP\htdocs\hs8-PHP Basics\p1-ifElseif\ifelseif.php on line 36"

If anyone has any idea what the issue might be, I would really appreciate it! This is my first time learning PHP, so I am kind of confused with this error.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');


    $salary = rand(0, 200000);


    const TAX_RATE_10 = 0.0;
    const TAX_RATE_50 = 15.0;
    const TAX_RATE_70 = 20.0;
    const TAX_RATE_100 = 30.0;
    const TAX_RATE_100_PLUS = 40.0;

    const INCOME_CAP_10 = 10000;
    const INCOME_CAP_50 = 50000;
    const INCOME_CAP_70 = 70000;
    const INCOME_CAP_100 = 100000;
    const INCOME_CAP_100_PLUS = 100001;

    $year = 2021;

    $tax = 0;
    $taxRate = TAX_RATE_10;


 ?>


 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <title>p1-ifElseif</title>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
     </head>

     <body class="w3-panel">
         <header class="w3-container w3-khaki"><h1>p1-If Elseif</h1></header>
         
         <main>
            <p>
                <label class="w3-input">Salary: <?php echo '$' . number_format($salary, 0); ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label class="w3-input">tax rate: <?php echo number_format($taxRate, 0) . '%'; ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label class="w3-input">tax: <?php echo '$' . number_format($tax, 0); ?></label>
            </p>
         </main>

         <footer class="w3-panel w3-center w3-text-gray w3-small">
             &copy; <?php echo $year; ?> Type your name here
        </footer>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to have any problems!

Comment: That makes me even more confused, because it still just shows the warning that they are undefined when I clearly defined them. Do you think there is any way it is just not reading the php?

Comment: Is what you have posted here all of your code? Have you copied all of your code or just some portion of it?

Comment: That is all of it, it is going to calculate federal tax. I am writing that part right now, but I don't wanna continue until I can resolve this issue.

Comment: I just ran your code on my machine, and the result: `Process finished with exit code 0`. No warnings! No errors! It just works fine.

Comment: Though you seem to have no problem, try to use `isset()` / `!empty()` to check if your variables are declared before referencing them or not. Use `isset()` and `!empty()` and then check the result.

Comment: Could it be that you edit and execute different files? I ask because that might explain why you get that warning (a warning, _not_ an error ...). And if I look at the file name you specify I wonder why there are not conditionals in the code you showed us ...

Comment: Can you _really_ post what like 36 contains in that file that is mentioned in the warning?

Comment: Copying and pasting your code, line 36 is the head close tag `</head>`. You didn't post the correct file.

Comment: UPDATE: Removed MAMP path in system environment variables, uninstalled MAMP, reinstalled it, and then added the path back and it works. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE:

1. Removed MAMP path in system environment variables
2. Uninstalled MAMP and reinstalled it
3. Added the path back and it works for me now

Thanks for the help everyone!